# Perl Mechanize bypass cert verification but encounters auth/login

Tags: perl, https, www-mechanize

im working within my company network and developing a new module for their systems. However, they have invalidated all ssl certificates thus i had to bypass the certificate verification.

Using mechanize's function to ignore ssl,

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
ssl_opts => {
    verify_hostname => 0,
},
```

I was able to bypass the certificate verification, however I encounter the following error
`Error GETing https://192.168.100.82/login;jsessionid=legizzgnfjd6g73szziuhboc: Could not resolve view with name 'auth/login' in servlet with name 'mvc'`.

I do not understand whether it is it because of the unaccepted certificate that i am not able to access the https site or is it something that i had done wrong. Please help me understand what is going wrong.

the site that i am connecting to is a module's website within the company network

Here is the running of my code after initializing mechanize to ignore ssl.

```
my $url = 'https://192.168.100.82';
$mech->get( $url );
die $mech->response->status_line unless $mech->success;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found was able to load the page successfully by controlling firefox with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox. However the downside is that it requires the firefox browser to be launched before it would be able to work.

I used cpan to install cpanm which allows me install modules which have dependancies , it would automatically detect these dependancies and install them along with the module you selected.

first, run `install cpan` (optional) , to update cpan. and refresh`reload cpan`.

then install cpanm  by typing `install App::cpanminus` and let it do its stuff.

afterwards. close cpan and launch cpanm by typing `cpanm` in the cmd.
Then type `install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. let it download everything completely

Next Firefox needs Mozrepl add-on for WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to control the browser so head over to the browser and get the add-on.

Once that is done, under tools, start MozRepl from tools tab in the browser and the script is ready to be launched.

P.S. mechanize::firefox object is still initialized with `verify_hostnames=>0`

Answer (score 1):

`Could not resolve view with name 'auth/login' in servlet with name 'mvc'` this is an error message comming from the Spring Framework. To me this means that you have passed the certificate check, you are reaching the site and you are not able to use a valid web session ( authenticate ). I suggest that you substitute the ; in the url with ? to pass the JSESSIONID parameter.

Comment: im sorry, im not very sure what do u mean. There is no semicolon in my url. Do you mean something like this? ->`https://192.168.100.82/?`.

Comment: I got it :) The thing is that the site requires authentication (login with username and password). So you need to do that before you start the Mech by hand and pass the cookie to the Mech via Cookie Jar. The other way is to include authentications steps (if possible) in your program.

Comment: how do i store my authentication in a cookie to pass to the mech?

Comment: Depends on the browser, but once you authenticate, view your cookies and look for JSESSIONID. Then when you call the Mech->new() pass to it parameter `cookie_jar => { 'JSESSIONID' => VALUE_TAKEN_FROM_BROWSER_COOKIE}`

Comment: `my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0,
    },
 cookie_jar => { jsessionid => '1i7br7udw4sf2524ohckpa9q'});


$mech->get( 'https://192.168.100.82' );` Here is my current code, i got the session id from logging in manually through the browser and copying the session id. however when i perform the get request. It actually requested a different session.

Comment: Check all you cookies, may be you need additionally a session key or smth.

Comment: the cookies do not provide any session id nor key. Could it be that mechanize simply could not obtain html encoding for the page? The site that im connecting to uses dynamic pages instead of static html pages.

Comment: make a simple LWP request on the command line to see what the Mech will retrieve as it is using LWP internally.

Comment: well its not really gonna help. I tried it and it is at the stage where certificate verification fails. On the command line there is no way to choose to ignore certificates either

Comment: use `export PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0` before you call the LWP on the command line. This will make it skip the SSL cert verification ;)

Comment: sorry im not very familiar with perl to know how to execute what you suggested but i found a work around. Thanks for all your help thus far